# How to populate column based on other columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to understand why this does not work in MS Access:

```
UPDATE main_records 
SET main_records.rece = Str(main_records.Nr) & "," &  Str(main_records.Pag);
```

The intent is to populate the `rece` column (63 chars string) in all records of `main_records` with the contents of `Nr` and `Pag` (converted to string and concatenated).

It looks so easy but ...

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: The query looks fine to me. Are you getting any error? I would try to run a SELECT first to make sure that the produced string is what you want. Any chance it can exceed 63 chars?

Comment: Please describe *does not work* which is not helpful to us.

Comment: Should not even be trying to save this calculated value. Perform this calculation when needed. If it can be calculated for UPDATE it can be calculated when needed.

Answer (score 0):

"the contents of Nr and Pag (converted to string and concatenated)"
If that is what you intend to do, you are to use a string conversion function

examples is
CStr( expression ).